# VBA - Check for consecutive clicks

Tags: vba, mouseevent

I´m completely new to VBA and thus would like to be informed:
I am working on a PPT that has a sort of Memory Game build in. 
To make it more interactive I decided to write a function that checks whether the links on two SmartArt-Nodes have been clicked consecutively, which will then delete these two Nodes, if the condition is met.

```
Function checkIfMatch(Node1 As SmartArtNode, Node2 As SmartArtNode)
If()
    Node1.Delete
    Node2.Delete
End Function
```

Does somebody have an idea to solve this problem?

Comment: You'll need a variable outside of procedure scope to "remember" what the previous click was. There are dozens of ways to do this...

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this specifically in PPT, but generally you will want an ```onclick``` to call a function that sets a public variable to the name of the shape that called the function. Then when you click a different shape check the last shapes name against the new shapes name and see if there is a match. You will probably need  a delimiter or something to split on to get the match.